# Default header and footer is not being recognized

Tags: civimail

CiviCRM 4.6.0

Default headers and footers are not being recognized so, unless I included the required tokens in the body of the email, Civimail will not send a test or schedule the email.

There was a typo in my original post. Version has now been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by upgrading to the latest version of 4.6.

Specifically the issue is https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16237